# Exim: How to rewrite the domain addresses to match the sender domain

Tags: email, url-rewriting, mail-server, exim

I am trying to rewrite the envelope from address domain. I would like it to match the sender address domain.

I have tried to do it using the following configuration.

```
begin rewrite
*@$primary_hostname $1@$sender_address_domain F
```

However the variable `$sender_address_domain` is not available in the rewrite section. Neither is the `$sender_address`.

I have also tried to set the `sender_address_data` in the routers section, but the variable `sender_address_data` is also not set (is null) in the rewrite section.

Any ideas? What am I missing?

Comment: Somebody voted to close this as "not about programming,"  however, I disagree. This configuration is on-topic the same what that programming rewrite rules in .htaccess is on-topic here.  See [Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281371/which-seo-questions-should-be-closed-as-non-programming-non-admin/382618#382618)